# Why did Dick Cheney say, "The SVTC"?

Tags: dialogue, vice

In *Vice* (2018), during the 9/11 terrorist attacks, the Vice President, Dick Cheney, asks Rice:

> Dick Cheney: Let's make sure those phone lines are working.
>
> Rice: Phones are go, sir.
>
> Dick Cheney: **The SVTC**. Let's contact the FAA, find out how many planes
>   are in the air.
>
> Rice: Yes, sir.

Why did Dick Cheney say, "The SVTC"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVTC stands for

## [Secure Video Teleconference](https://www.acronymfinder.com/Secure-Video-Teleconference-(SVTC).html)

It's secure method of linking up with governmental and miltary locations across the world via telephone & satellite.